# Ckeditor call function after newpage button on the toolbar is clicked

Tags: ckeditor

Ckeditor call function after newpage button on the toolbar is clicked

Comment: any progress? - I am also wondering how to do this. This kind of question has been asked many times on the CKEditor forum without resolution ...

Answer (score 2):

Use 'afterCommandExec' and 'beforeCommandExec':

```
editor.on('afterCommandExec', handleAfterCommandExec);
function handleAfterCommandExec(event)
{
    var commandName = event.data.name;
    alert(commandName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to catch the paste event:

```
editor.on('paste', your_cb_fn);
```

However this doesn't seem to work for the button actions:

```
// does nothing
editor.on('Bold', your_cb_fn);
editor.on('bold', your_cb_fn);
```

The solution may be to edit the plugins in _source/plugins to create triggers, though that is not ideal.